# Outlook VBA find and add link; keeps skipping first hit

Tags: vba, email, replace, outlook, find

I'm a long-time beneficiary of the helpful advice folks on here have offered to others (sincere thanks, everyone), but this is my first time actually posting. My VBA skills are lackluster at best.

This is driving me nuts: I have an Outlook macro that's supposed to comb through an email message before it's sent and replace citations to our policy documents, all of which have a prefix of "A&P-" with a link to that document.

It actually works great, except that it stubbornly refuses to capture citations if they're the first word in the email. So, for example, if I have a list of entries that looks like this:

A&P-I-A-1-100, A&P-II-B-2-200, A&P-III-C-3-300

the script will add links to the second and third entry (and as many more as I want to add) but skip the first one entirely. Weirdly, if I add any characters at all to the start of the email (even just hitting the space bar a couple of times) this doesn't happen. It doesn't impact citations at the start of subsequent paragraphs either. Just that first word.

Here's the code I'm using. Any help very, very appreciated!:

```
Sub Citation3()

Dim myInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim myObject As Object
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim rngStory As Word.Range
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim mySelection As Word.Selection
Dim strItem As String
Dim strItem2 As String
Dim strLink As String

Set myInspector = Application.ActiveInspector
Set myObject = myInspector.CurrentItem
Set myDoc = myInspector.WordEditor
Set mySelection = myDoc.Application.Selection

For Each rngStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    With mySelection.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "A&P-*-*-[0-9]{3}"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True

    If mySelection.Find.Execute = True Then
        While mySelection.Find.Execute
        strItem = mySelection.Text
        strItem2 = Replace(strItem, "A&P", "AP")

  mySelection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=mySelection.Range, _
  Address:="http://www.google.com/" & strItem2 & "_document.shtml", _
  TextToDisplay:=strItem

End If

End With

Next rngStory


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lines are:

```
If mySelection.Find.Execute = True Then
    While mySelection.Find.Execute
```

When they're isolated like that, you can probably see what's happening.

You're doing one `Execute` in the `If` statement which finds the first occurrence of the pattern you're looking for and then immediately do another `Execute` in the `While` loop that now finds the second occurrence of that pattern, therefore ignoring the first match completely. After that, the code loops around the `While` loop and picks up any remaining matches correctly.

To fix this, simply remove the `If` and corresponding `End If` lines, because you don't need them. The `While` loop will take care of everything.

Now, for some observations.

In your code I don't see `Next` statement for your `For Each` loop, or a `End With` statement for your `With` block, or a `Wend` statement for your `While` loop, or a `End Sub` for that matter. I can only assume you've cut and pasted only selected bits of your code, so I'll ignore that.

You should probably indent your code a little better to make it easier on others (and on you!) to read and identify any potential errors.

Finally, I'm a little confused by your matching pattern: `"A&P-*-*-[0-9]{3}"`. It would work equally well as `"A&P*[0-9]{3}"` or `"A&P-*-*-*-[0-9]{3}"`. In the latter, note that there are 3 dashed bits of text between the `P` and the 3-digit number (according to your format specification for citations), whereas your original pattern only accounted for 2 dashed bits.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! That actually did the trick; I thought for some reason I needed to limit application of the while-wend loop to times when the selection was found (I've frankensteined this thing up from pieces of code across the internet, so I may have inherited that  assumption from a source where it made more sense). Took care of the missing wend, though the Next I think is  up there.  This is awesome though, thanks again!